# using snowflake JDBC driver with Presto

Tags: jdbc, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I want to read data from snowflake datastore into my app via presto.  I would like to make snowflake as one of the data sources for the Presto. can I use Snowflake provided JDBC driver with presto? thanks

Answer (score 4):

Based on github repository:

https://github.com/prestodb/presto

I see presto-mysql, presto-spark and presto-redshift etc, but I don't see presto-snowflake.

And I tried to added snowflake.properties under /usr/local/Cellar/prestodb/0.263/libexec/etc/catalog on my Mac, but presto server failed to start with error:

```
2021-10-16T11:08:25.505+1100    ERROR   main    com.facebook.presto.server.PrestoServer No factory for connector snowflake
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No factory for connector snowflake
    at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument(Preconditions.java:216)
    at com.facebook.presto.connector.ConnectorManager.createConnection(ConnectorManager.java:208)
    at com.facebook.presto.metadata.StaticCatalogStore.loadCatalog(StaticCatalogStore.java:123)
    at com.facebook.presto.metadata.StaticCatalogStore.loadCatalog(StaticCatalogStore.java:98)
    at com.facebook.presto.metadata.StaticCatalogStore.loadCatalogs(StaticCatalogStore.java:80)
    at com.facebook.presto.metadata.StaticCatalogStore.loadCatalogs(StaticCatalogStore.java:68)
    at com.facebook.presto.server.PrestoServer.run(PrestoServer.java:150)
    at com.facebook.presto.server.PrestoServer.main(PrestoServer.java:85)
```

It does not look like that Presto supports Snowflake yet.

Comment: great! thanks.  Much appreciated. ..rao

Comment: Just updated my answer, does not look like it is supported, but still checking.